# What do we call someone whose English is weak?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a student, and I am interested in knowing the formal (polite) and informal (insults) terms.

Comment: An [ELL.se], of course.

Comment: Are you looking for a politically correct term, or do you want to insult someone?

Comment: i am interested in knowing both the terms

Comment: @TusharRaj You dirty polyglot you! (This is what I *always* think when someone apologizes to me for their "poor" English. I think "(A) Your English is pretty damn good and (B) However bad you *think* it is, it's lightyears better than my French (or whatever language they speak)").

Comment: Someone with poor English skills.

Comment: On this site, a pineapple.

Comment: EFL lingo "s/he's a beginner" is perhaps the most accurate and PC term.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun to describe the person or are you happy with adjectives describing their language skills?

Comment: You can call them anything you'd like - they won't be able to understand you!

Comment: Only English or it can be any language?

Answer (score 1):

You could say that he is **not proficient** in English.

(Note: Although it might sound offensive to some people.)

Comment: Somebody could have very good English writing and reading skills and not be *proficient* in English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, if someone is competent enough in English then of course he will be proficient. [ I wanted to argue more but got scared of your rank ; ) ]

Answer (score 1):

Try using '**inept** or **incompetent** at English'. As *inept* as well as *incompetent* mean that the person being referred to is not skilled at something, these may be taken in a derogatory sense.

Comment: Maybe you should correct your preposition to the more idiomatic `at`. (good/bad **at** English)

Comment: @TusharRaj: Thank you. I've made that change. Honestly speaking, I was quite confused about the preposition myself.

Comment: Nothing to worry about. Welcome to EL&U. It's good to see more Indian users.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some informal phrases to describe ability.

"I'm sorry, I only know a few words of Hindi."

"My Greek is not up to much."

"My knowledge of Latin is patchy."

"I know enough to order a meal in Italian."

Comment: My favorite excuse in any every language: _I must apologize for the lamentable state of my <insert language>. I sincerely hope my amateuristic attempts at communication serve their purpose at an adequate level_. Rest assured that no one will take your inability to speak the language serious anymore.

Comment: @oerkelens, shouldn't that be "... *seriously* anymore."? :-)

Comment: @oerkelens Or they might just assume that anyone who readily admits to being a non-native speaker and still expresses himself so sesquipedalianly must indeed have learnt all his English at a terribly posh school and doesn't really know how to talk to normal people about normal things in English at all—i.e., is not fluent. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Nonfluent**

Fluent:

> able to speak or write smoothly, easily, or readily

[From Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nonfluent)

I think it's [nonfluent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonfluency), although there's support for [unfluent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unfluent).  [Influent is wrong.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/influent)

Fluency is usually used to refer to the tipping point between the somewhat broken, labored diction of a new learner and the easier, more fluid style of a proficient speaker.